# Query SAP ECC6 user create view in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, view, azure-data-factory, abap, sap-erp

I am trying to get the data Delta i.e the change in SAP ECC 6.0 tables (`EKKO`, `EKPO`, etc) for current day to achieve that I have joined the `CDHDR` and `CDPOS` tables and created my own view `Z_INCREMENTAL` using transaction code `SE11`. Now when I try calling the data in Azure data factory using `RFC_READ_TABLE` function module, empty table get returned with just the column names.

Executing the query `Select * from Z_INCREMENTAL` in `ST04 > Additional Functions > SQL Command Editor` seem to return the correct results.

Any suggestions on why no data is being retrieved in Data Factory?

Thanks!

Comment: The function module RFC_READ_TABLE raises an excpetion, if there is any error (missing authorization, no data in the table, table does not exists, etc.) Can you check if any of these exceptions is returned?

Comment: The view does exist, i am able to query it from the SAP GUI. Used the similar SAP table connector to fetch data from other tables without any errors.

Comment: `Now when I try calling the data in Azure data factory using RFC_READ_TABLE function module` how do you call it? what is the view type? what are they key fields?

Comment: Have SapTable as source dataset, i am providing view as table name, The view is a Database View. These are the Key fields of both tables `MANDANT,
OBJECTCLAS,
OBJECTID,
CHANGENR,
OBJECTCLAS,
OBJECTID,
CHANGENR,
TABNAME,
Table,
TABKEY,
FNAME,
Field,
CHNGIND`